# Why is a div's height half the size of the margin

Tags: html, css

When a div's height is specified via percent and the margin is the same, the margin is twice the size of the height. This makes a margin that is half of the height value appear the same. Why is this?

```css
.test {
  height: 5%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  outline: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test 1</div>
```

Comment: Your div will not use a percentage height, unless it's parent div has had it's height specified. In your example, there is not 5% height showing, as it doesn't have anything to base it on relatively.

Comment: Gotcha, my browser was displaying it as I intended while JSFiddle won't. What is the best way to specify 5% without using something like viewport (just to avoid dealing with scrollbars)?

Comment: Viewport won't affect your height, and I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Why do you need to use percentage height values anyway?

Comment: I was saying that I wanted to do something like 'height: 5vh', but that can be affected by scrollbars.

Comment: Is this for mobiles? You don't get scrollbars on mobile devices usually though.. vh should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's defined in the spec, the percentages you used are not based on the same origin :

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

So if you set any margin as a percentage, it will relate to the *width* of the parent and not the height :

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  background: crimson;
  margin-top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

As mentioned in the comments, using viewport units would be the best option here.